# How to count datetimes with same day?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list with DateTimes how can I count all the datetimes with the same day using linq?

I need to use the result to find out how many of one day there is compared to how many there should be.

Comment: Define day. Do you mean a week day like monday or tuesday? Or a date? And what do you mean by "how many should be".

Comment: What gruping precision is required? Is time part important?

Comment: one day i might have 5 readings with a certain DateTime.Day and I was only suposed to have 4 readings that leaves me with a difference of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will group on the day (by day I mean 1st, 2nd etc.) and ignore all other date parts and then return a list of each day and the number of times that day was found in the list

```
var dateInstances = listOfDates.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Day).Select(x => new {Day = x.Key, Instances = x.Count()}).ToList();
```

Comment: maybe a stupid question but how do you return Instance ?

Comment: you can access it like any other list e.g. dateInstances[0] or dateInstances.First() or dateInstances.Where(x => x.Day == 1)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `GroupBy` on `DateTime.Date`:

```
int count = dates.GroupBy(d => d.Date)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Count();
```

This will count all `DateTimes` in the list which date is not unique.